# How do ( ... ) and { ... } interact with subshell creation with pipes in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand a difference between shell subprocess invocation using round brackets and curly brackets. I thought that curly brackets do not launch a subprocess, but it seems that they do launch a subprocess.

```
#!/bin/sh

a=1
b=1

( a=2; ) | ( a=3; )
{ b=2; } | { b=3; }

echo "a=$a"
echo "b=$b"
```

This script prints

```
a=1
b=1
```

So it seems that all invocations are run inside subprocesses. Is there any difference between them in that context? I understand that if I would use `&&` and `||`, then `{..}` will not launch a subprocess, but I'm trying to understand how pipes work.

Comment: Not "all invocations", but "all pipelines". And even that's not entirely true -- POSIX sh doesn't specify the behavior, and some shells will in some circumstances put some pipe component (first, last, or such) inside the parent process.

Comment: ...look at the `lastpipe` option in bash, for instance, which would run `a=3` or `b=3` of your pipelines in the parent shell when active (only takes effect under a number of restrictive circumstances defined in the docs).

Comment: Aha, so `()` always spawns a subprocess and `{}` may spawn a subprocess if it's required or may re-use current process if it's possible. Is that correct?

Comment: It's close enough to correct, yes. `( ... )` spawns a process of its own volition, `{ ...; }` doesn't spawn a process, but can be used in contexts where something else will [be that a pipe, a coprocess, a `&`, or similar], and won't prevent that behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll mark your answer as correct if you'll write one.

Comment: Believe it or not, I couldn't find an existing question to mark this as a duplicate of. So I had nothing to do but answer it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To demonstrate that it's the pipeline itself that's generating the subshell, and that curly braces won't change this either way:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Base: $BASHPID"
( echo "In (): $BASHPID" )   # This will differ from the base
{ echo "In {}: $BASHPID"; }  # This will match the base

# In bash, these will both differ from the base
echo "Pipeline, default config:"
{ echo " X: $BASHPID" >&2; } | { echo " Y: $BASHPID" >&2; }

# This is exactly the same without the {}s
echo "Pipeline, no {}s, default config:"
echo " X: $BASHPID" >&2 | echo " Y: $BASHPID" >&2

# Only the former will differ from the base if running a new enough bash
shopt -s lastpipe
echo "Pipeline, lastpipe enabled:"
{ echo " X: $BASHPID" >&2; } | { echo " Y: $BASHPID" >&2; }
```

Running this locally with bash 4.3, I get:

```
Base: 82811
In (): 82812
In {}: 82811
Pipeline, default config:
 X: 82813
 Y: 82814
Pipeline, no {}s, default config:
 X: 82815
 Y: 82816
Pipeline, lastpipe enabled:
 Y: 82811
 X: 82817
```

Note that since all pipeline components run simultaneously, there's no defined ordering of which of `X` or `Y` will emit output first; however, with `lastpipe` enabled, the last pipeline component is invoked in a shell that's already up and running (doesn't need to be `fork()`ed off from the main process), which slightly modifies the likelihood of who writes to stdout first.

Answer (score 3):

`{ ... }` doesn't spawn a sub-shell. What you're seeing is due to the fact you're using `|` between 2 curly list commands.

It will be evident with this test:

```
$> b=1

$> echo $BASHPID
4401

$> { echo "X. $BASHPID"; b=2; } | { echo "Y. $BASHPID"; b=3; }
Y. 46902

$> echo $BASHPID
4401

$> declare -p b
declare -- b="1"
```

You can see that `{ echo "Y. $BASHPID"; b=3; }` gets executed in a different sub-shell hence changes made to `b` are not reflected in current shell where `b` is still `1`.

Comment: I'm not following you. You are writing that `{ ... } ` doesn't spawn a sub-shell yet you demonstrated that it spawned a subshell because $BASHPID is different and b variable wasn't changed.

Comment: @vbezhenar, it's not the `{ ... }` that spawned the subshell, it's the pipeline. `{ ... }` doesn't spawn a subshell itself, but it also doesn't prevent something else you're doing from creating one.

Comment: @vbezhenar: I wrote it clearly at the start that **What you're seeing is due to the fact you're using `|` (pipeline) between 2 curly list commands**

Comment: I wanted to understand the difference between those forms when using a pipeline. So it turns out that `()` always spawns a sub-process and `{}` may spawn a sub-process as well (in that case there's no difference) or may run its body in the parent shell (in that case there's a difference because that body may alter parent's variables, etc) and the exact behaviour unspecified and differs between shells and their options.

Answer (score 1):

Round brackets execute commands in a subshell.
Curly brackets execute commands in the current shell:

```
$ echo $BASHPID; (TEST=test; echo "sub:$TEST;$BASHPID"; exit 1);\
> { echo "current:$TEST;$BASHPID;$?"; }
2920
sub:test;3700
current:;2920;1
```

Another difference is that curly braces require spaces between them and the enclosed commands and a semicolon after the last one while round braces don't.

This all is documented at the [`bash`'s man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), "Compound commands" section.

---

One exception (or rather, another aspect) is if you use pipes:

```
command1 | command2
```

In this case, *both* commands are executed in *separate* subshells - *regardless of that they are* (and that includes compound commands). The "Pipelines" section of the man page documents this.

Comment: "subshell" does indeed imply "subprocess" -- if there isn't a `fork()` call involved, it's not a subshell. (Granted, there's no `execv()`-family call, which is a critical difference between subshells and other, more conventional kinds of subprocesses).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, you do see that the reported PID is the same, don't you? That surprised me, too. The important thing of "subshell" is that it is a separate execuion environment.

Comment: `$$` isn't your real PID in a subshell. Use `$BASHPID` for that, and you'll see that the PIDs aren't **actually** the same.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay, I stay corrected. Never noticed this.

Comment: ...btw, it's not strictly true that `command1 | command2` always runs both components in separate subshells -- see the `lastpipe` option, in which case `command2` can be run directly by the parent shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the man page says _"Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)."_ `lastpipe` is [new in `bash` `4.2`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).

Comment: yes, lastpipe is new -- I reference that via the "new enough bash" qualifier that in my answer -- but it's not *that* new; bash 4.3 has been out for a substantial while now.