# Append to an array variable from a pipeline command

Tags: arrays, bash, pipeline

I am writing a bash function to get all git repositories, but I have met a problem when I want to store all the git repository pathnames to the array `patharray`. Here is the code:

```
gitrepo() {
    local opt

    declare -a patharray
    locate -b '\.git' | \
        while read pathname
        do
            pathname="$(dirname ${pathname})"
            if [[ "${pathname}" != *.* ]]; then
            # Note: how to add an element to an existing Bash Array
                patharray=("${patharray[@]}" '\n' "${pathname}")
                # echo -e ${patharray[@]}
            fi
        done
    echo -e ${patharray[@]}
}
```

I want to save all the repository paths to the `patharray` array, but I can't get it outside the `pipeline` which is comprised of `locate` and `while` command.
But I can get the array in the `pipeline` command, the commented command `# echo -e ${patharray[@]}` works well if uncommented, so how can I solve the problem?

And I have tried the `export` command, however it seems that it can't pass the `patharray` to the pipeline.

Comment: `echo -e` will also expand backslashes in paths (not that they are very likely to be there...).

Comment: Thanks for reminding, the better way is to use `printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, appending to an array variable is better done with `array[${#array[*]}]="value"` or `array+=("value1" "value2" "etc")` unless you wish to transform the entire array (which you don't).

Now, since [pipeline commands are run in subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896360/how-do-and-interact-with-subshell-creation-with-pipes-in-bash), changes made to a variable inside a pipeline command will not propagate to outside it. There are a few options to get around this (most are listed in [Greg's BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)):

- **pass the result through stdout instead**

  - the simplest; you'll need to do that anyway to get the value from the function (although [there are ways to return a proper variable](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions))
  - any special characters in paths can be handled reliably by using `\0` as a separator (see [Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array) for reading `\0`-separated lists)

    ```
    locate -b0 '\.git' | while read -r -d '' pathname; do dirname -z "$pathname"; done
    ```

    or simply

    ```
    locate -b0 '\.git' | xargs -0 dirname -z
    ```
- **avoid running the loop in a subprocess**

  - avoid pipeline at all

    - temporary file/FIFO (bad: requires manual cleanup, accessible to others)
    - temporary variable (mediocre: unnecessary memory overhead)
    - process substitution (a special, syntax-supported case of FIFO, doesn't require manual cleanup; code adapted from [Greg's BashFAQ/020](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)):

      ```
      i=0    #`unset i` will error on `i' usage if the `nounset` option is set
      while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        patharray[i++]="$(dirname "$file")"    # or however you want to process each file
      done < <(locate -b0 '\.git')
      ```
  - use the `lastpipe` option (new in Bash 4.2) - doesn't run the *last* command of a pipeline in a subprocess (mediocre: has global effect)

Comment: Finally, `xargs` combined with `-0`. Great answer.

Answer (score 8):

Bash runs all commands of a pipeline in separate [SubShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell)s. When a subshell containing a `while` loop ends, all changes you made to the `patharray` variable are lost.

You can simply group the `while` loop and the `echo` statement together so they are both contained within the same subshell:

```
gitrepo() {
    local pathname dir
    local -a patharray

    locate -b '\.git' | {                      # the grouping begins here
        while read pathname; do
            pathname=$(dirname "$pathname")
            if [[ "$pathname" != *.* ]]; then
                patharray+=( "$pathname" )     # add the element to the array
            fi
        done
        printf "%s\n" "${patharray[@]}"        # all those quotes are needed
    }                                          # the grouping ends here
}
```

Alternately, you can structure your code to not need a pipe: use [ProcessSubstitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)
 ( Also see the Bash manual for details - `man bash | less +/Process\ Substitution`):

```
gitrepo() {
    local pathname dir
    local -a patharray

    while read pathname; do
        pathname=$(dirname "$pathname")
        if [[ "$pathname" != *.* ]]; then
            patharray+=( "$pathname" )     # add the element to the array
        fi
    done < <(locate -b '\.git')

    printf "%s\n" "${patharray[@]}"        # all those quotes are needed
}
```