# Modules not loaded into environment

Tags: bash, environment-modules

I have the following line in my `.bashrc` file:

```
cat "$HOME/.module_list" | while read m; do echo "Loading module $m..."; module load "$m"; done
```

where `$HOME/.module_list` is a file that contains the name of a module to load on each row. When `.bashrc` is sourced, the line goes through each module in the list one by one and seemingly loads them, but afterwards, when I do `module list`, none of the modules are loaded.

Does this line create a new scope into which the modules are loaded, which is then terminated as soon as the line finishes, or why aren't the modules still loaded afterwards? How can I successfully load all modules from the list and still have them be loaded afterwards?

Comment: by default commands after the pipeline (`|`) would run in a subshell and its env would be gone when the `| command` completes.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/024 (I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Also see [Append to an array variable from a pipeline command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37229058/4154375), [A variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16854280/4154375), and [Capturing output of find . -print0 into a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1116992/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to load your modules names into an array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t modules < ~/.module_list

module load "${modules[@]}"
```

An other solution is to use a `while read` loop, making sure to avoid the `|`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r m
do
    module load "$m"
done < ~/.module_list
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! In the second alternative, which command is it that gets `~/.module_list` as input? I'm not that familiar with the `<` syntax.

Comment: The whole `while` loop (i.e. each command in it) will "share" the content of `~/.module_list` as input; in this aspect, it's 100% equivalent to `cat ~/.module_list | while`

Comment: Also, what is `IFS` in the second alternative?

Comment: It's not really needed here, it's just a habit of mine. Setting `IFS` to the empty string in the `read` command is for making sure that the leading/trailing blanks characters are not stripped from the line